# I want to install Steam on two different locations

Tags: steam

I would like if possible to install Steam at two different locations, physically separate on two different IP addresses (MACs) and can play games purchased. It's my house and my cottage, where I could play on both computers.

Comment: Ok. What's your question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: **yes, it can be done**

As Steam is a cloud service, this is percisely what the platform excells at.

If you have two differents computers, simply install Steam, log into your account, download the games you want and play on. If you have Steam Guard enabled, Steam may ask you to verify the new location by a code sent to you by e-mail.

However, some games may have additional DRM that limits the number of computers the game can be installed on during its lifetime. But these are not tied to Steam or your user account.

Edit: I've been told in the comments that you can  now log into same account on multiple computers to use something called In-Home Streaming. You just can't play games on both of them at once. Altough, this seems to be limited to same home network. Anyways, thanks Kexlox.

Also, here are links for more information on [Steam Family Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) and [Steam In-Home Streaming](http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/)

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, and this is not against steam legal staff, and this will not block my account?

Comment: It is what Steam is *designed for*. You can't/shouldn't, however, use this to share your games with another person. That's why there is the limitation of one Steam running per user account. Steam does allow limited sharing with its Family Share functionality, tough.

Comment: Also, I added a comment about game spesific DRM to the answer, as these may add some limitations to where you can install a game.

Comment: Ok thanks i will learn little more for Famaly Share

Comment: You can have steam logged into the same account more than once now, because of In-Home Streaming.  You can't play games on both at the same time, but you don't have to log one out before you log the other in.

Comment: @astralravenko If it's just you using both of these locations, Family Sharing is not needed. If you're trying to sneakily share games with someone, Family Sharing will not help you much either: when someone else is playing a game you're sharing, you can't play any games yourself.

Comment: +1 for family sharing. I use it. @SevenSidedDie nope, you can kick them if you want.

Comment: @ardaozkal Which doesn't help the other person much, does it? Point is: they don't need to look at Family Sharing if they are in fact just wanting to play their own games in two different places.

Comment: @ardaozkal 9.9 I guess you're not familiar with this community's views on piracy if you're bragging about that.

Comment: Wow! My comment got deleted. It's not pirating, I guess. As I play the game I own on two different computers.

Comment: @ardaozkal Uh-huh. When you said that you can just kick the other person you're sharing your games with when you want to use your games, it was pretty clear that you weren't talking about just you playing on two computers at different times. It's OK, you know better what's permitted here and what's not, now. There's no need to draw more attention to the faux pas by inventing a cover for it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I just have 2pc and my sister loves to Play scribblenauts. And I love to Play csgo. Not cover. Real. Out of this conversation, too long comments. If you don't believe, add me on steam and I'll explain it. Link in my profile.